# Tensorflow model uses entire memory and OOMs system

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management, out-of-memory, nvidia-jetson

When Running a model trained for object detection I'm running out of memory when calling tf.run()

```
2018-06-26 18:32:16.914049: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.55GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-06-26 18:32:17.393037: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.31GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-06-26 18:32:23.825495: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.31GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-06-26 18:32:24.659582: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.11GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-06-26 18:32:29.902840: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.20GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-06-26 18:32:30.955526: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.29GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-06-26 18:32:37.434223: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1328] OP_REQUIRES failed at where_op.cc:286 : Internal: WhereOp: Could not launch cub::DeviceReduce::Sum to count number of true / nonzero indices.  temp_storage_bytes: 1, status: too many resources requested for launch
```

Is there some type of process of training a model to ensure a model doesn't require a large amount of RAM for inference?

Is there some way I'm able to convert my model to use less memory?

I've tried some of the graph transforms but they didn't seem to do much.
I've also set the GPU limit to be 40% of ram but that didn't help either.

I should have about 4gb-5gb of ram available.

These are the main problems I think I might have.

1) The model that was trained off of inception V3 instead of a mobile model.

2) Images of somewhat of a large size were labeled and used for transfer learning.

-EDIT It appears to be due to poor allocation of memory with tensorflow and Cuda on ARM architectures.

Comment: This problem is usually associated with more than one application trying to access the same GPU memory, try running the program after restarting your machine. If that fails port to a smaller architecture e.g VGG16

Comment: @SimbarasheTimothyMotsi thanks but the first portion of your response wasn't the issue.